# Substitute string if the word is in a dictionary pyspark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, dictionary, pyspark, replace

I'm a newbie in PySpark.

I have a Spark DataFrame named `dic_df2` that has a column `diccionario`.

```
+--------------------+
|         diccionario|
+--------------------+
|{abierta -> abierto}|
|{abrigada -> abri...|
|{absoluta -> abso...|
|  {abuela -> abuelo}|
|{abuelastra -> ab...|
|{acabada -> acabado}|
|{academica -> aca...|
|{aclarada -> acla...|
|{acogida -> acogido}|
|  {adelia -> adelio}|
|{adivina -> adivino}|
|{adjudicataria ->...|
|{administrativa -...|
|{adriana -> adriano}|
|{aduanera -> adua...|
|{adversaria -> ad...|
|{afeitada -> afei...|
|{aficionada -> af...|
|{afirmativa -> af...|
|{aforisma -> afor...|
+--------------------+
```

Also I have another Spark DataFrame named `mylist` that has a column `final1` with array of string with words.

```
+--------------------+
|              final1|
+--------------------+
|[noefar, fabricac...|
+--------------------+
```

I'd like to change everyword that I find `diccionario` if not I left the same word.

For example the word "abierta" is in the dataframe `mylist` and also is in the dictionary so I'd like to change this word for 'abierto'. Otherwise, if the word is not in the dictionary I don't change the word.

Comment: can you provide some code that will generate your sample data?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, it is helpful for the community if you provide some more details of the attempts you've made so far. Please review the guidelines here:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask